# RESTFUL wrapper for Windows Azure Mobile services

Tags: .net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am pretty new to Windows Azure Mobile services (WAMS) and want to get started only once I get all my doubts cleared. From what I understand, we can build a service layer on the cloud with support for data storage, authentication, push notifications etc. The service layer and the features it offers can be used by multiple mobile platforms including Windows Phone, Windows Store, Android, IOS and so on. However, from whatever material I've read, in order to use this service layer, the SDK for the corresponding mobile technology would have to be used. For e.g. in order for an Android app to use this service layer, the Android SDK for WAMS would have to be used. Also, the basic logic (excluding the server side scripts) to perform operations/call methods on WAMS would have to be written in Android. Same would be the case with other platforms. Thus, even though we have a cloud layer, considerable logic would still have to be written in native platforms. 
Would it be better instead to have a RESTFUL service wrapper over a WAMS implementation in .NET which can then be consumed by all platforms without me requiring using individual SDKs?

Comment: the server side code is already exposed via REST, the client SDKs are the ones wrapping the REST interaction with the server.

Comment: If you want to see how this wrapper is implemented you should have a look at the [Windows Azure Mobile Services GitHub site](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/tree/master/sdk).

Answer (score 0):

WAMS is supposed to use when data storage is in the Azure. REST API is standard layer which will talk to your backend/data.

Android, iOS, WP etc. are mobile platform & having their SDKs to build frontend, backend layers.

As whole backend is on the cloud, we need to work on frontend only. As Google Cloud Platform(GCP), Windows Azure, Amazon Web Services(AWS) providing SDKs for these platforms, we can utilize it to talk to Backend through REST API/wrapper.